# Search words using MySQL fulltext

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, match, against

I have read so many query examples using 
mySQL and fulltext indexes,

but I am still not able to make an apparently simple query.

I would like to search a list of words (ie. 'green, black, yellow, white, orange') 
in text field of records, ordering results by the number of these being contained,
regardless to relevance.

Just would like to list as first the record including four of the words, 
then the one with three 
and so on.

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

A simple query with sorted result might not be possible.But u can write a query to find the record set which contains the words u have mentioned.

Comment: Not Sure , but hope this will help you `SELECT * FROM table_colors WHERE color_code in('green', 'black', 'yellow', 'white', 'orange');`

Comment: sorry, doesn't work, because color_code is not a single color but a text containing one or more.